# Can't get data from model class in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a file called: orderdetails.dart where there is a class:

```
class OrderDetails {
  final shipmentNumber = "26";
}
```

need to retrieve this shipmentNumber var and display into the widget as below:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  OrderDetails orderDetails;
  _MainPageState({this.orderDetails});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Icon(Icons.message),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Icon(Icons.person),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          height: 90,
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                elevation: 5,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  width: 160,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Card(
                          color: Color(0xfffeaf0d),
                          child: Container(
                            width: 40,
                            height: 40,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.local_shipping,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13),
                        child: Text(
                          orderDetails.shipmentNumber,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 35,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

but in the text widget can't get the value requested got

> NotSuchMethodError: The getter "shipmentNumber"" was called on Null receiver Null.

If I call into the main

```
final shipmentNumber = "26";
```

it works but I need to call this variable from external widget.

Answer (score 1):

`orderDetails` on the state is never set so it's always null.

You can either set the `orderDetails` in the state (1) or pass it as widget parameter (2).

1. We can initialize the value in the initState method of the state.

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  OrderDetails orderDetails;

  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    
    // setState is not needed in initState
    orderDetails = OrderDetails()
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

2. Pass it to the widget and then use the value in the state's build method

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final OrderDetails orderDetails;

  const MainPage({Key key, this.orderDetails}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      widget.orderDetails.shipmentNumber, // Using widget's data
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    );
  }
}
```

But still, remember to pass the value to it: `MainPage(orderDetails: OrderDetails())`

Comment: I did second option but nothing it doesnt work I pout again the full code below